# How to dynamically add gap to flowpane embedded in scrollpane if user resize scrollpane

Tags: java, javafx

How to dynamically add a gap to a FlowPane embedded in a ScrollPane if the user resizes ScrollPane?

I have a window with a GridPane.
Inside this GridPane I have a ScrollPane.
In this ScrollPane I have a VBox.

I add an array of circle in a FlowPane and i add this FlowPane to the VBox.

I would like to dynamically set the space gap between circle depending of the size of the window or ScrollPane.

For the moment I put a gap of 5, but if the window is resized really big, because of the FlowPane, the content stays on the left. I would like the content to take all the horizontal space.

I tried with a bind, and a changeListener, but I didn't find a solution.

Comment: Should the number of columns be predetermined? Are all the children the same width?

Comment: yep ! there are 2 columns but their size can change, all the children have the same width

Comment: did you delete your previous questions? now everybody is back to zero info - and you still don't provide a clear description (including a [mcve]) of what exactly you are after. Pretty sure that you are barking at the wrong tree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: Like you said i restarted my explanation because of your previous answer. I was not finding a way to explain better, so i restarted yes, now i have other answer, so i guess its more clear. thanks for your previous answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the special case of a constant number of columns and children of equal size, I recommend using a `GridPane` with appropriate `ColumnConstraints`.

This allows you ensure the column widths are the same in addition to specifying the alignment of the nodes in the columns:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    final int columns = 2;
    ColumnConstraints columnConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
    columnConstraints.setPercentWidth(100d/columns);
    columnConstraints.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER);

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();

    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        grid.getColumnConstraints().add(columnConstraints);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        grid.add(new Circle(50), i % columns, i / columns);
    }

    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(new VBox(grid));
    scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true); // make sure GridPane content resizes with viewport

    Scene scene = new Scene(scrollPane, 300, 300);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Modifying the child list of the `GridPane` becomes a bit more complex, since the row/column indices need to be adjusted/set, but it's not too difficult. Just make sure the column index of a child at index `i` is `i % columns` and the row index `i / columns`.

Comment: perfect ! i understood, i'll try this.